# i18n jade templates from ajax calls in sails

Tags: internationalization, sails.js, pug, i18n-node

I'm having an issue with i18n my sails+jade app. When templates are loaded after an ajax call, the __ and __n functions are not visible, but I don't understand why?

I have wrapped the jade.renderFile call and am sending the request object as well, so the jade template gets the __ and __n functions in the options object.

I can only use __ although I am passing both, because only __ is exposed globally in the 18n hook in sails.

EDIT: I managed a dirty workaround to get it to work by requiring sails/node_modules/i18n and passing the __n function to the template from the wrapper.

I still can't understand why both functions aren't exposed.

Any help or hints or explanations appreciated